# How to do string replacement character with function?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a function that takes 3 string parameters and replaces the characters.

The first parameter is the word, the second is the letter I want to replace, and the third is the letter I want it replaced with. This has to work for any string.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
def replace_letter(phrase,letter,replace):
    phrase = phrase.replace(letter,replace)

    print(replace_letter(phrase,letter,replace))

def word_and_phrase_processing():
    phrase=input("Enter the phrase: ")
    letter=input("Letter to replace? ")
    replace=input("Replace it with? ")
    replace_letter(phrase,letter,replace)

 word_and_phrase_processing()
```

Comment: `f"{phrase}"` is the same as `str(phrase)`, by the way

Comment: You do understand the difference in print and return, yes? Remove `print(phrase)`. As answered, this is "dead code". Do use `print(replace_letter(phrase,letter,replace))`... Or `return replace_letter(...)` and `print(word_and_phrase_processing())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a commented & corrected version of your code:

```
#import string # not used

def replace_letter(phrase,l,r):
    #phrase = f"{phrase}"         # useless
    result = phrase.replace(l, r) # use variable names, not strings
    return result
    #print(result)  # not evaluated (after return)

print(replace_letter("cat","a","o"))
```

output `cot`

Comment: good point, I forgot beginners love print :p

Comment: Thank you guys so much omg!!!! This worked:)))

Comment: I'd just to `return phrase.replace(...)`

Comment: How do I do it if I want to change the function call? Won't I have to change the print statement then?

Comment: @OneCricketeer advanced users wouldn't even define a function, I guess the goal here was to play around a bit ;)

Comment: @amanda The print statement doesn't change. The function parameters do

Comment: @OneCricketeer please check the edit! I actually have to do it with input im sorry!

Comment: @mozway Please check the edit! I thought it was simple, but it is saying I must do it with input :(, I wrote a new function, but I must pass it to the other function.

Comment: @amanda remove your `return phrase`, nothing is executed after a `return`

Comment: I think I see, so print just prints a value, but return stops the execution. I edited the post again, thank you for all the help by the way. still trying to get it to run

Comment: Yes, `return` stops the execution **and returns a potential value** ;)

Answer (score 1):

The correct code shall be:

```
import string

def replace_letter(phrase,l,r):

    phrase = f"{phrase}"
    result = phrase.replace(l, r)
    return result

print(replace_letter("cat","a","o"))
```

I modified two things:

1. Print result is not in the right place (either you put it before the `return` statement or put it as I did as a print of function call)
2. When you are using the function arguments inside the function definition you mentioned:

   result = phrase.replace("l", "r")

This tells python to replace the character "l" with character "r".
What I did is to remove " from your code to tell Python to use `l` and `r` variables not the constants "l" and "r".

Comment: But if I wanted to make it to where the function does it for any string how can I do it? Without changing the print statement

Comment: you can add the print statement inside the function. but I believe this is not a good habit in this context unless you are debugging your code. make your function either return something to use it inside your code. or do something like print what you need. In case you decided to put print inside the function. put it before the return statement. return shall be the last executed line inside your function.

Comment: Thank you!!! I'm starting to understand more, but now im confused with the input. (check edit pls)

Comment: Take care with the print statement. You called the function. replace it with print(phrase)

Comment: You guys! I finally did it, thanks so much everyone.